# Need help in table sort through column search

Tags: php, mysql

I am a total beginner in PHP and i am trying to fix a script i have. I am trying to put filter search boxes over every column (it is a products table). Once the search is made the entire row(s) should be displayed with the search term in it corresponding to the column it was made in. It is pulling the data from the mysql database

Comment: best of luck as i heared right now learn before asking initial questinos

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please avoid asking open ended questions. This forum is for specific coding issues you run into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a form above your table header. have the textboxes for each column. Then on the click of "Go", grab the non-empty textboxes and fill them as part of the search query and then form the query and set that output to the grid / table.

you may refer to joomla paging code for a sample..